# Wrap content in absolute div only based on max-width

Tags: html, css, absolute, word-wrap

I have absolute positioned div that is used as a tooltip with white background. So his position is set based on mouse coordinate.
I want my tooltip to have `max-width` but if smaller then `width` should be based on content.

If I put `max-width` and `wrap` text is wrapping after every word.

**EDIT**
here is an example of usage
https://jsfiddle.net/miniverse_solutions/sgct5qux/

I also realized that translate3d is missing in up. First I found this example where it works like I want it to work
http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/vVhWR/

Next thing I realized that my parent nodes have `width = 0`.
When I add `width = 0` in that sample it works like mine, so then I tried removing in my example same `width = 0` but it still didn't work. It looks like `translate3d` is messing with it.

Comment: please show an example code and what you already tried

Comment: Where is your code and what tooltip you used?

Comment: I find it hard to understand what your asking here. Are you having problems with word wrapping and/or the scaling of a tooltip?

Comment: @Persijn I'm having problem with setting the div width based on the content inside but having max-width as well. If I set the wrapping on, every word is in the separated line

Answer (score 0):

Since having only one wrapped absolute div with `width = 0` reproducing the same problem, it looks like to me that when two absolute positioned divs (one inside the other) automatically sets outer div width to 0.

Removing absolute positioning from outer div solved the problem.

Don't know why was outer `div` even absolute when he is always rendered right under `body` with `top` and `left` having value `0`.